# growisofs fails with unable to O_EXCL /dev/scd0: someone was in time to remount?

Tags: dvd, burning

When trying to burn a DVD it sometimes happens that growisofs will fail with:

```
$ sudo growisofs -speed=8 -dvd-compat  -Z /dev/scd0 -J -r .
Executing 'genisoimage -J -r . | builtin_dd of=/dev/scd0 obs=32k seek=0'
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
0.23% done, estimate finish Fri Sep 16 14:49:33 2011
0.46% done, estimate finish Fri Sep 16 14:49:33 2011
0.69% done, estimate finish Fri Sep 16 14:49:33 2011
:-( unable to O_EXCL /dev/scd0: someone was in time to remount?
```

This only seems to happens when burning multiple DVD's in a row and I think it happens when I eject an automounted disc without manually unmounting it first, which implies that something is keeping the drive busy, `lsof` and `fuser` however fail to find a process still accessing the drive. Rebooting makes the problem go away.

How can I find out what process is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been running into issue now again a few times and I am reasonably confident that it is really nothing more then having an shell open that is still in /cdrom/ and thus prevents a proper unmounting of the drive.

Still no idea on how to find the trouble causing shell with `lsof` or `fuser`, but there is another way that should work:

```
sudo ls -l /proc/*/cwd  | grep -i cdrom
```

Comment: had this issue too, with 12.04 LTS, default desktop GUI setup (running from the livecd on a USB stick, actually).  Hit the eject button on the drive to umount and open the tray,but now growisofs can't open /dev/sr0 with O_EXCL.  I guess it didn't really unmount?  But there's nothing about it still in /proc/mounts, and no processes with a cwd in /media or anything.

 I can mount and unmount burned discs with no complaints or effects on the problem.  Is there a bug open for this on Launchpad?

Comment: update: actually some mounting and careful unmounting do appear to have solved it.  /proc/<pid>/cwd doesn't show the working directory of a process still CDed to a force-unmounted filesystem, so I did find a shell that might have been CDed to a CD while I was trying to burn the first time

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your `/etc/fstab` has the following line for your `cdrom`:

```
/dev/cdrom /media/cdrom auto rw,noauto,user,exec 0 0
```

Change it to

```
/dev/cdrom /media/cdrom iso9660 rw,noauto,user,exec 0 0
```

, reboot and try if it still happens.

<sub>[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/problem-with-growisofs-596398/)</sub>